# Update values of an XML type column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a problem! We have an SQL Server table that has an XML type column. This column have  a number of nodes and some of them have misspelled values.
I would like to write a script which updates all occurrences of this misspelling! The problem is I don't know how to do it!
Let's say that one of the nodenames in the XML column is `TEST` and some of these nodes have the misspelled value `MISSPELLED` and I want it to be modified to `CORRECT` after the update.
Is this possible to do and if so how?
Thanks in advance.
/Kaunda

Answer (score 0):

You can modify XML column data by following way :

```
CREATE TABLE Test (C1 XML)
INSERT INTO Test 
VALUES ('<REF>
            <Person>
                <FirstName>John</FirstName>
                <LastName>Smith</LastName>
                <System>
                    <User><Systemid>System1</Systemid><Type>UserId</Type><Useridentity>Userid1</Useridentity></User>
                    <User><Systemid>System2</Systemid><Type>UserIdx</Type><Useridentity>Userid2</Useridentity></User>
                    <User><Systemid>System2</Systemid><Type>Department</Type><Useridentity>Finance</Useridentity></User>
                    <User><Systemid>System3</Systemid><Type>UserId</Type><Useridentity>Userid3</Useridentity></User>
                    <User><Systemid>System4</Systemid><Type>UserIdx</Type><Useridentity>Userid4</Useridentity></User>
                </System>
            </Person>
        </REF>
')


UPDATE [Test]
SET C1.modify('replace value of (/REF/Person/System/User/Type/text())[1] with "UserId"')
WHERE C1.value('(/REF/Person/System/User/Type/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') LIKE '%UserIdx%'
```

**UPDATE :**

For multiple values update in column, you need to write script like below :

```
DECLARE @strSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Index INT
DECLARE @NodeCount INT

SET @Index = 1
SELECT @NodeCount = C1.value('count(/REF/Person/System/User/Type)', 'INT') from Test

WHILE @Index <= @NodeCount
BEGIN
    SET @strSQL = ' UPDATE [Test]
                    SET C1.modify(''replace value of (/REF/Person/System/User/Type/text())[' + CAST(@Index AS VARCHAR(10)) + '] with "UserId"'')
                    WHERE C1.value(''(/REF/Person/System/User/Type/text())[' + CAST(@Index AS VARCHAR(10)) + ']'', ''varchar(max)'') LIKE ''%UserIdx%'''

    EXEC(@strSQL)

    SET @Index = @Index + 1
END
```

Comment: Thanks Upendra for your reply. A question: What does the [1] mean in your solution (in the ET C1.modify('replace value of (/Sample/NodeTwo/text())[1] with sql:variable("@newValue")'))?

Comment: One more thing: In my case there may be more than one misspellings in the XML column for each row.

Comment: @user3292601 : [1] is index of record for that node. If there are multiple records with same node then that index is used to get data. If this is the case for you then please provide your existing XML, so I can guide you

Comment: @user3292601 : Where is the XML ? please provide exact XML in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help Upendra! It has been very helpful. I now have to put the code into a stored procedure since there thousands of rows to go through and each one of them may contain a number of misspellings! I couldn't get your CAST to work in my stored procedure!

Comment: Hi Upendra, I get the following message when I try to compile it in a stored procedure in SQL Server: "The argument 1 of the XML data type method "modify" must be a string literal." Do you understand the message?

Answer (score 0):

```
<REF><Person><FirstName>John</FirstName><LastName>Smith</LastName><System><User><Systemid>System1</Systemid><Type>UserId</Type><Useridentity>Userid1</Useridentity></User><User><Systemid>System2</Systemid><Type>UserIdx</Type><Useridentity>Userid2</Useridentity></User><User><Systemid>System2</Systemid><Type>Department</Type><Useridentity>Finance</Useridentity></User><User><Systemid>System3</Systemid><Type>UserId</Type><Useridentity>Userid3</Useridentity></User><User><Systemid>System4</Systemid><Type>UserIdx</Type><Useridentity>Userid4</Useridentity></User></System></Person></REF>
```